# IE6 li tags not aligning

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-6

I am a bit pressed for time so I am sorry that this is brief.

I am trying to align these six li tags that act as drop downs, IE7, IE8 and all the good browsers work fine but IE6 continues to be stubborn and put them all over the place, you can find the page [here](http://www.astute.co.uk/).

I am using this CSS to place them inline.

```
/* I beleive this is the important bit? FROM HERE */
li.rathdown {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}
/* TO HERE */

li.rathdown * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

li.rathdown ul {
    width: inherit;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}

li.rathdown-sub {
    position: relative;
}

li.rathdown-sub ul {
    z-index: 99;
}

li.rathdown img.arrow {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 3px;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

I also have another problem, in IE7 and IE8 the bottom of the page curls up slightly, any ideas?

Thanks for any suggestions you can give.

Comment: I think its to do with the a tags not being floated? Thats what I am reading, but when I float them, it falls apart...

Comment: OKAY Fixed problem one, it was due to only appling formatting to li.rathdown, not the remaining li's without any class. I still dont get why there is a gap at the bottom though?

Comment: This is hard to debug without the html. If you can provide a link it will allow SO peeps to debug much more quickly since we can use firebug to quickly modify your html/css.

Comment: I did, in above the CSS, I have fixed them both now anyway. The gap at the bottom was due to the height of the page, I think it was being shortend in IE by somethings padding (???) and the menu was fixed by applying the styles to all of the li's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed them both now. The gap at the bottom was due to the height of the page, I think it was being shortend in IE by somethings padding (???) and the menu was fixed by applying the styles to all of the li's.

Sorry for the bad answer. It's a bit of an edge case really.